# Programming Visio ActiveX control

Tags: c#, visual-studio, activex, visio

My task is to use Microsofts Visio ActiveX control (Visio Viewer) to visualise a Visio document in a web page and to catch the events generated by user clicks.

My immediate problem is to generate the AxVisOcx assembly. Explained below:

> ActiveX control wrapper assembly that
>   allows the control to be embedded
>   within a Windows Form

Im trying to follow the instructions on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa168480(office.11).aspx) but the step where I actually generate the ActiveX control wrapper is not explained. I have tried installing the Visio Viewer and running the aximp.exe on the vviewer.dll but it says the the dll does not include an ActiveX control.

So my questin is, how do get hold of the .ocx or the .dll file for the MS Visio ActiveX control which I then can run in aximp.exe to be able to use in my Visual Studio project?

Answer (score 1):

I found a better instruction for the Visio Viewer 2007 [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392798.aspx).

AxImp generated two dll files, AxVisioViewer.dll and VisioViewer.dll. I really hope this solves my problem!